# Will AWS Lambda wait for my response?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, request, aws-lambda

I'm using AWS lambda as SQS listener in my project. Some time no response got in my log, most of the time it's working.
code

```
    console.log('Befor Req ' + post_data);
    // Set up the request
    var post_req = http.request(post_options, function(res) {
        res.setEncoding('utf8');
        res.on('data', function (response) {
            console.log('Request data' + post_data);
            console.log('Response ' + response);

        });
        res.on('error', function (err) {
                console.log(err);
        })
    });
    // post the data
    post_req.write(post_data);
    post_req.end();
```

Here I got all fine in before request, sometimes the log inside the request not get logging.
I check the other side request and response are logged and all fine.

Is this any specific issue with AWS LAMBDA?

Comment: Could you please provide the whole Lambda `handler`? When do you call the `callback()`?

Answer (score 0):

The log inside the request is an asynchronous callback's either log inside your on success or your failure callback should prints.

If not There are two posibilities.
 one is you are terminating lambda before that async code completed

[image]

posibility no 2 is, your lambda got timesout before that async request completed .  see this scenario may works on sometime and fails on other time. It depends on our async execution time and lambda timeout

[image]

TO ensure this check your **cloudwatch log** for lines task timedout after x second. And you  will be get 502 on that time if you are using lambda proxy in API gateway. see below

[image]